# "git svn clone" from almost-standard svn layout

Tags: git, git-svn

We have a subversion repository that we're migrating to git.

The layout of the svn repository is *almost* standard, but at some point in the history some idiot developer (okay, it was me) accidentally created a directory, call it "/foo", in the repository root instead of trunk.

"foo" lived there for a few weeks before being moved to "/trunk/foo" where it should have been all along.

Now when I do a "git svn clone --stdlayout [...]", I miss the parts of the history that occurred outside the trunk.

Is there a way of "merging" the early changes to "/foo" into the history of master on git?

**edit ** alternatively, is there a way of getting those missing revisions onto a branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this will get you what you want but you are welcome try:

1. clone the foo folder to a separate folder. to do that you have to find out the revision range it was in its original location (/foo). say it was created on rev 100 and was moved to /trunk/foo on rev 200. in this case your command should look like:

   `git svn clone -r100:200 http://server/foo`

you will get another git repo foo.

1. Go to the main git repository and add foo as a remote:

   `git remote add foo /path/to/foo`
2. fetch:

   `git fetch foo`

now you can set a local branch on remotes/foo/master or merge it to your master.
you will not have the correct history graph since the new commits and the original one will not have common history but you will have all dev history in one git repo.